# X-Axis date fromatting in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
$(function () {
    $('#dc-item-demand-graph').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            padding : 0
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            startOnTick: true,
            type: 'datetime',
            pointInterval: 5 * 24 * 3600000,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#f36c6c',
                dashStyle: 'Solid',
                value: 2, // Value of where the line will appear
                width: 2 // Width of the line    
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 700,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        //tooltip: {
        //    valueSuffix: '°C'
        //},
        series: ItemDemandChartData()
    });
});
function ItemDemandChartData() {
    var data = [{

            name: 'At DC',
            dashStyle: 'dot',
            color: '#616fc6',
            data: [400, 390, 300]
        }, {
            name: 'At stores',
            dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
            color: '#ffdb03',
            data: [300, 320, 360, 320, 500]
        }, {
            name: 'ROP Generated',
            dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
            color: '#00c4db',
            data: [200, 300, 500, 450, 400],            
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 3,
                symbol: 'triangle',
                //symbol: 'url(/Content/Img/markdown.PNG)',
                color: '#00c4db'
            },
        }]

    return data
}
```

above is the code for the graph which i tried.
in which i have format X-axis values as shown in the image attached.

I am not sure where should i change the code in x-axis categories or series options? kinldy help me.

thanks in advance!!

[image]

updated [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/o2hcy3sn/3/) :

Comment: The  pointInterval parameter should be defined in the series object, not in the xAxis.

Answer (score 0):

this is because your data is saying about only y axis values but the x axis in date time.

```
data: [300, 320, 360, 320, 500]
```

so it is taking 0 as start time and y points for every 1 second. if you want to have dates on x axis make the data as two dimensional as shown here

```
data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 300],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 320],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 360],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 320],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 500]
            ]
```

instead of UTC date you can your time stamp as well.

here is the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime-irregular/).

you can have the datforamt as you want

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/) is a example for date formatting (this example is showing with regular intervals because of pointstart and pointInterval)

Comment: this answer was useful for me, though :)